# Cannot get window.location.origin in React return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issue with `windows.location.origin` which I can not figure out what I am missing. When I use it and `console.log` in `useEffect` it works without problem but when I try to render it in return It gives me `Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined` error. I realized also now when i come my page from previous pages It renders hrefOrigin but when I refresh the page, I get error again. Thanks in advance!

```
// @ts-nocheck
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { isEmpty, path } from 'ramda'
import { ProductContext } from 'vtex.product-context'
import { defineMessages } from 'react-intl'
import fetchRequest from '../utils/fetchRequest'
import styles from './styles.css'
import IconScrew from './Icons/IconScrew' 

const KitItems: StorefrontFunctionComponent<> = () => { 

  const valuesFromContext = useContext(ProductContext)
  if (!valuesFromContext || isEmpty(valuesFromContext)) {
    return null
  } 

  const hrefOrigin = window.location.origin
  
  useEffect( () => {  
       console.log(window.location.origin)
  }, []);
 
  return (<div className={styles.kitItemsMain} >
              {valuesFromContext.selectedItem.kitItems && hrefOrigin && valuesFromContext.selectedItem.kitItems.map(kitItem => 
              <div key={kitItem.itemId} className={styles.kitItemsMainInner}>
                        <div >
                            <img className={styles.kitImages} src={kitItem.sku.images[0].imageUrl} />
                        </div>
                       <div>
                            <h3> {kitItem.sku.name} </h3>
                            <p>Reference: {hrefOrigin} </p>
                            <p>{kitItem.sku.referenceId[0].Value}</p>
                        </div>
                        <p className={styles.kitAmount}> {kitItem.amount} </p>
                        <p> {kitItem.sku.sellers[0].commertialOffer.Price} </p>
              </div>
               )} 
          </div>)
}

export default KitItems
```

Comment: kinda weird, what happens if you do `console.log(hrefOrigin)` ?

Comment: It gets the origin as I want. Problem occurs just when I try to use it in return. I realized also now when i come my page from previous pages It renders hrefOrigin but when I refresh the page, I get error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a ref or a state variable to store the window location ,  windows.locaton.origin is perhaps only available after the component is fully mounted hence the useEffect log worked

```
// @ts-nocheck
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState ,useRef} from 'react'

const KitItems: StorefrontFunctionComponent<> = () => { 


  let hrefOrigin = useRef()
  
  useEffect( () => {  
       hrefOrigin.current= window.location.origin
  }, []);
 
  return (<div className={styles.kitItemsMain} >

                       <div>
                            <h3> {kitItem.sku.name} </h3>
                            {hrefOrigin.current && <p>Reference: {hrefOrigin.current}</p>}
                       </div>
          </div>)
}

export default KitItems
```

Comment: This solution is working perfect, thanks a lot!